# TexMaker or TexPad?

Tags: texmaker, texpad

I am new to Latex programs and I need to download one. I have a MAC and I was wondering which is the best program between TexMaker and TexPad without considering the economic point of view.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! The best program for TeX, in my opinion, is TeXShop (https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/). It is a thoroughly Mac-like application from an extremely responsive developer (Dick Koch). I have tried other programs (TeXMaker, TeXPad and TeXStudio), but for features and (most importantly) reliability, I cannot recommend TeXShop too highly. It is frequently updated, a not unimportant consideration in these turbulent Macintosh times.

Comment: You get TeXShop automatically if you install MacTeX which also gives you the full TeX Live Distribution.

Comment: Thanks! But I really liked the interface of TexPad.... the other don't have an interface as good as its, at least it doesn't seem. What about it? Is it a good program for TeX?

Comment: I personally like TeXstudio (https://www.texstudio.org/) best, and there's a Mac version --- perhaps give that a try.